# How to make a FMX.ListBox with Variable Column Width in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm trying to change the width of the hours column only, but I'm not getting it.
If I set the `ListBoxItem.Width` via code it just doesn't work. The Listbox has the `ItemWidth` property but it changes the width of all items.

Can someone help me?

[image: Agenda]

Comment: Like you, I don't see any property for changing width of individual columns. Is there a reason why you don't use a `TGrid` for example?

Comment: @TomBrunberg I need to customize each cell individually, using frames. If there is no commitment for that time, I display a frame, if there is a commitment I use another frame detailing some information and etc.

I didn't actually try to use TGrid because I don't know if it allows me to load frames into cells.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. I'm afraid the `TGrid` would not be to any help here then. There are some layout components, like `TGridLayout` and `TGridPanelLayout` etc. The latter of those is resizable per column, but is difficult to work with at design time (I recommend selecting `SizeStyle = Absolut`. Sorry but I'm running out of other ideas.

Comment: Thanks Tom, i will try  these Layout components!